# Issue with compilation of C library on Ubuntu

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, target

Sorry in advance for the probably dumb question.

I am trying to compile a custom library, written in C, on an Ubuntu 22 OS ($SYS = Linux-generic-x86_64). The rough structure of the available Makefile is

```
ADS  =       /destination/folder

.KEEP_STATE:
.PARALLEL:

CFLAGS = -xc99
CPPPFLAGS-x86_64  = -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLinux -DLITTLE_ENDIAN
CPPFLAGS += -I../include -I../../common
CPPFLAGS += $(CPPPFLAGS$(TARGET_ARCH))

CC = cc
VARIANT = ../$(SYS)/.dynamic/
.KEEP_STATE_FILE: ../$(SYS)/.make.state

linux   := CFLAGS  += -g -fPIC

BBSOURCES= (several .c source files)
DDSOURCES=  (several .c source files)
WWSOURCES=  (several .c source files)
TTSOURCES=  (several .c source files)

LSOURCES=   $(BBSOURCES) $(DDSOURCES) $(WWSOURCES) $(TTSOURCES)
LOBJECTS=   $(LSOURCES:%.c=$(VARIANT)%.o)

linux:  $$(LOBJECTS)

$$(VARIANT)%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@
```

According to the README, the commands for the compilation should be

```
sh -c '$(MAKE) linux'
sh -c 'cd $(SYS)/.dynamic; $(MAKE) -f .dynamic_makefile dynamic'
```

where the content of the file $(SYS)/.dynamic/.dynamic_makefile is

```
LD     = ld
LIB = ../compiled_library.so
dynamic:
       $(CC) -shared -o $(LIB) *.o -lnsl -lc

clean:
    rm *.o
```

However, when I try, I get the error

> make: *** No rule to make target '$(LOBJECTS)', needed by 'linux'.  Stop.

Is there something wrong I am doing?

Comment: You have `linux:  $$(LOBJECTS)`.  By using two dollar signs here you've escaped the dollar sign so instead of the variable `$(LOBJECTS)` this refers to the literal string `$(LOBJECTS)` which of course is not a file that can be built.  Why did you add the extra `$`?

Comment: Ah, I did not write that makefile by myself...
by the way, deleting that extra $ gets me the following error now:
```make: *** No rule to make target '../Linux-generic-x86_64/.dynamic/opens.o', needed by 'linux'.  Stop.```
where opens.c is the first of the source files listed in BBSOURCES

Comment: You have another $$ lurking around.

Comment: Yes, there is another `$$(LOBJECTS)` as a target in the rule to build the objects.  As before, that's wrong because it means the literal string `$(LOBJECTS)`, not the contents of the make variable `LOBJECTS`.